# Installing Yaboot on an external USB hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, usb-storage

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on an external USB hard drive but I can't install [Yaboot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaboot).

My Mac is a PowerPC G4 iMac flat panel.

I know that it's possible to boot on USB using open firmware and I know how to do it, but since Yaboot is not installed when I try to boot on this external USB drive I get a not possible symbol with a grey background on the screen.

I'd like to install Yaboot on the external drive but I can't mount it on OS X (I have a bad superblock error).

When I try `sudo mount_hfs /dev/disk1s3 /Volumes/1`, I get this message: `mount_hfs: Invalid argument`

If I could mount this volume I could generate the Yaboot config file.

I tried to use DiskWarrior but I can't see this external USB hard drive on it.